# Last updated time of a channel/playlist - YouTube

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

Is there any endpoint from YouTube API which returns the last update time for a channel/playlist(by updatetime I mean the last time a video is added or deleted from/to channel/playlist)?
I did some reserch and saw [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), but I could not find it! However I'm pretty sure it is possible to fetch this info from the API.

Comment: V3 of the API doesn't expose the last updated time ... only the created time. So if your goal is to actually utilize the data (for example, sort playlists based on when they were last updated), you'd have to be pretty roundabout; you could consider, for example, retrieving a handful of playlistItems and using their publishedAt property to determine the last time something was added to that playlist or channel. However, if your goal is just to determine whether or not a list has been updated, you could also use etags: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags

Comment: It seems etag things is doing what I need to do \'when your application requests a stored resource again, it specifies the ETag associated with that resource. If the resource has changed, the API returns the modified resource and the ETag associated with that version of the resource. If the resource has not changed, the API returns an HTTP 304 response (Not Modified), which indicates that the resource has not changed.\' But I have no idea how I should pass etag in request, there is no example; could you please help me with that... Thanks

Comment: I tried to get get a channel data which is not changing but after refreshing a couple of times it seems ETag jumps to different values! Any idea why is that?